# How to validate the Microsoft MVP profile link is valid or not using C#?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

How to validate the Microsoft MVP profile link is valid or not (**is that profile is existing or not**) using **c#** or **javascript**.

*Microsoft MVP profile links samples :*

- https://mvp.microsoft.com/es-es/PublicProfile/xxxxxxx
- https://insider.windows.com/en-gb/MVPs/xxxxxxx
- https://mvp.microsoft.com/zh-tw/PublicProfile/xxxxxxx
- https://mvp.microsoft.com/en-us/PublicProfile/xxxxxxx?fullName=xxxxxx%20%20xxxxxxx
- https://mvp.microsoft.com/it-it/PublicProfile/xxxxxxx?fullName=xxxxx%20%20xxxxx

Please any one given solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

According to my little research there is an [api developer portal](https://mvpapi.portal.azure-api.net/). If there is a proper api for your requirements, you can retrieve information via ajax request.

Comment: In this API, there is no option for checking the user by profile link.